# (master) at end of terminal prompt

Tags: linux, git, terminal

I am just learning more with git and that type of thing and so I just used init with git. After doing this and doing a commit to a repository. I still have (master) at the end of my terminal prompt. I am using a linux ide. How can I back out of this and get back to a normal terminal prompt?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please edit your question by including more details (what IDE are you using? How do you add the branch name to the prompt, etc?) so that it is useful to people that are bad at git like me, and so that you can maximize your chances of getting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem that needs to be solved. The prompt is just saying that you are on the master branch. It is useful information.

However if for aesthetic reasons you wish to restore the standard shell 
prompt, so that it doesn't display (master), see e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/574485/how-to-return-default-ps1-prompt

Answer (score 1):

The Git branch will be shown (unless you change the PS1 variable as mentioned in Robin Green's answer) if the current directory is in the Git repository. This means all that you need to do is `cd` (change directory) out of the Git repository.

```
pwd    # this will show where you are currently 
cd ..  # go to parent directory
cd ~   # go to user's home directory
```

---

Note that this not only applies to the root folder, but also *any* subdirectory, e.g., for the tree shown below, *bar* is the root of the Git repository, and we know that because the *.git* folder resides directly within it. This means that *bar*'s parent, *foo*, and *bar*'s sibling, *eggs*, are not in the repository.

```
foo  (outside of repo)
|
+----bar  (inside of repo)
|    | 
|    +----.git
|    |
|    +----spam  (inside of repo)
|
+----eggs  (outside of repo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my terminal which I had base at the beginning and master at the end, (base) meant I was running in an anaconda environment and exit solved that problem, and master relates to what level of the directory you are currently in.