# What does (master) next to folder path mean?

Tags: git, github

I"m trying to figure my way around GitHub and Git. After setting up a new account and new repository, all my folder paths have (master) next to it.

What does this mean exactly? and do I need to change it?

Comment: "*all my folder paths have (master) next to it*". Where? In your shell? If so, which OS do you use? In the browser? On GitHub? Be more specific.

Comment: Probably your shell is set up to show the active git branch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(master) at end of terminal prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50537690/master-at-end-of-terminal-prompt)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+master+prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

master is the default branch in git. you should read the documentation for more details : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell